# Update index.html with db values after selecting option from select field rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to RoR, and currently in process of achieving some testing task.
What I need is to select `update_date` from `select_tag` of my form, hit Show button and after that i want to see on that same page(index.html in 'update-container' div) corresponding information from db according to that selected `updated_date`. I was trying to google it as well as 'stackoverflowed' it, but each time i have just got stuck more & more.

My index.html.slim:

```
.container
    .child-container
        .show-date
            = form_tag('/show',
                method: :get,
                remote: true,
                enforce_utf8: false,
                :'data-update-target' => 'update-container',
                class: 'select_date')
                do
                    = collection_select(:id, :id, Dashboard.all, :id, :update_date)

                = submit_tag 'Show', name: nil

        #update-container
```

My routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :dashboards, only: [:index, :show]
    root to: 'dashboards#index'
end
```

My dashboards_controller.rb:

```
class DashboardsController &lt; ApplicationController
    def index
         @dashboards = Dashboard.all
    end
    def show
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

From that point i`ve got "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/show"):".

I will very appreciate any help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The ```resources``` method just ganerates the ```/dashboards``` and ```/dashboards/:id``` routes in this case. You dont have a /show route (if you check the rake routes output, you can see your available routes).

Comment: @stockholm_syndrome
Try to change `show` at your form tag to `dashboard_path` (without quotes)

Comment: @cnnr, thanks for comment. However using this solution i still receive "No route matches..."

Comment: My case is the first comment by @Fede Bonisconti. Form works with "/dashboards".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case you have to use following code in `routes.rb`.

```
get '/show', to: 'dashboard#show'
```

If you use `resources :dashboards`, this will make show route automatically to  `/dashboards` or `/dashboards/:id`.

Comment: that is the simple solution and it was under my nose. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

To sum up, really the big deal for me was exactly the point i mentioned in the title of question. Well, it was written in many sources, however i stumbled.

I want to provide solution that works for me(maybe helpful for someone like me).

`config/routes.rb`:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
    resources :dashboards, only: [:index, :show] 
    get '/show', to: 'dashboards#show'
    root to: 'dashboards#index'
end
```

`app/controllers/dashboards_controller.rb`:

```
class DashboardsController < ApplicationController
    def index
        @dashboards = Dashboard.all
    end

    def show
        @dashboard = Dashboard.find(params[:id])
        respond_to do |format|
            format.js
            format.html
            format.xml
        end
    end
end
```

`app/views/dashboards/index.html.slim`:

```
.container
    .child-container
        .show-date
            = form_tag('/show',
                method: :get,
                remote: true,
                enforce_utf8: false,
                class: 'select_date')
                do
                = select_tag(:id, options_for_select(Dashboard.all.collect{|d| [d.update_date, d.id]}), {include_blank: true})
                = submit_tag('Show', name: nil)

        table[id="update-container"]
```

`app/views/dashboards/_dashboard.html.slim`

```
thead
tr
  th Carousel
  th Newbie
  th Other
tbody
  tr
      td #{dashboard.carousel_info}
      td #{dashboard.newbie}
      td #{dashboard.others}
```

`app/views/dashboards/show.js.coffee`:

```
$('#update-container').empty()
$('<%= j(render @dashboard) %>').appendTo("#update-container")
```

I really appreciate all for their help! And i'm ready to answer any question.